# user error, stream exceeds limit [2,048] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: stream exceeds limit [2,048]

Tags: hive, oozie, hue

```
user error, stream exceeds limit [2,048]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: stream exceeds limit [2,048]
```

I'm getting this error while using `hue` to do a job.

Comment: thx! @kiran Biradar

Comment: it has settled. because of the auth of server.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have 'capture output' true in the Oozie action, and the output of the command is too much.